# Java слияние двух объектов (Json, ObjectMapper)

Tags: java, json

Есть два объекта класса MyBean (в классе всего полей 15 типа int и String):

```
MyBean old = new MyBean();

MyBean diff = new MyBean();
```

diff это объект который приходит в метод, для изменения old. 
У него как правило, одно поле не равняющееся null. Это поле надо изменить в old.
В Json это выглядит вот так:

```
diff: {"nat_udp_update_time":333}
old: {"nat_udp_update_time":15,"static_sip_local_port":1111}
```

Результат нужен такой:

```
old: {"nat_udp_update_time":333,"static_sip_local_port":1111}
```

Как удобнее сделать слияние этих объектов?

Я пробовал через ObjectMapper, но не нашел подходящего метода.

Comment: В голову приходит только написать свой "слиятор", который будет этим заниматься перебирая каждое поле и перенося нужные данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю можно попробовать использовать метод `putAll` класса `JSONObject` из библиотеки `json-simple` например:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("nat_udp_update_time", 15);
        jsonObj.put("static_sip_local_port", 1111);

        JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj2.put("nat_udp_update_time", 333);

        jsonObj.putAll(jsonObj2);
        System.out.println(jsonObj);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
{"static_sip_local_port":1111,"nat_udp_update_time":333}
```

Надеюсь то, что надо.